# How to spy on dynamically called function

Tags: mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm working with Javascript, Mocha, Chai and SinonJs. What I'm trying to do is to spy on a method "equals" that is called dynamically by another method "compareUsingOperator". The following code shows my class "StringComparator" with the two methods "equals" and "compareUsingOperator".

```
export default class StringComparator {

    private compareFunctionList: {[key in "=" | "!=" | "<>" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">="]: Function};

    public constructor() {
        this.compareFunctionList = {
            "=" : this.equals,
            "!=" : this.notEquals,
            "<>" : this.notEquals,
            "<" : this.lessThan,
            "<=" : this.lessThanOrEquals,
            ">" : this.greaterThan,
            ">=" : this.greaterThanOrEquals,
        };
    }

    public equals(value1: string, value2: string): boolean {
        if (typeof value1 != "string" || typeof value2 != "string") {
            console.log(value1);
            console.log(value2);
            throw new TypeError("Invalid data type!");
        }

        return (value1 === value2);
    }

    public compareUsingOperator(operator: "=" | "!=" | "<>" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">=", value1: string, value2: string): boolean {
        if (typeof operator != "string" || typeof value1 != "string" || typeof value2 != "string") {
            throw new TypeError("Invalid data type!");
        }

        if (!Object.keys(this.compareFunctionList).includes(operator)) {
            throw new ReferenceError("Undefined operator!");
        }

        const fn: Function = this.compareFunctionList[operator];
        return fn.call(this, value1, value2);
    }

}
```

And this is my Unit test:

```
            describe("compareUsingOperator", () => {
                context("calls", () => {
                    comparator.validOperators.forEach((operator) => {
                        it("the proper function according to the given operator", () => {
                            sinon.spy(actual, "equals");

                            actual.compareUsingOperator("=", comparator.value1, comparator.value2);

                            assert.called(actual.equals);
                            actual.equals.restore();
                        });
                    });

                });
            });
```

In my Unit test I set a spy on the "equals" method like that:

```
sinon.spy(actual, "equals");
```

"actual" is an instance of "StringComparator".

In the next step I'm calling:

```
actual.compareUsingOperator("=", comparator.value1, comparator.value2);
```

In this method the following code is executed:

```
const fn: Function = this.compareFunctionList[operator];
        return fn.call(this, value1, value2);
```

This is the call to the "equals" method. And this is also my problem. I want to know if "equals" is called or not. I'm using the following assertion:

```
assert.called(actual.equals);
```

The answert I get from chai/sinon is:

```
AssertError: expected equals to have been called at least once but was never called
```

The expected behavior should be a green test.

What is wrong with my Unit test? With the help of console.log I can prove that "equals" has been called.

Regards

Florian

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer myself. I had to replace:

```
   const fn: Function = this.compareFunctionList[operator];
   return fn.call(this, value1, value2);
```

with:

```
    const fn: string = this.compareFunctionList[operator];
    return this[fn](value1, value2);
```

And this:

```
private compareFunctionList: {[key in "=" | "!=" | "<>" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">="]: Function};

    public constructor() {
        this.compareFunctionList = {
            "=" : this.equals,
            "!=" : this.notEquals,
            "<>" : this.notEquals,
            "<" : this.lessThan,
            "<=" : this.lessThanOrEquals,
            ">" : this.greaterThan,
            ">=" : this.greaterThanOrEquals,
        };
    }
```

like that:

```
private compareFunctionList: {[key in "=" | "!=" | "<>" | "<" | "<=" | ">" | ">="]: string};

    public constructor() {
        this.compareFunctionList = {
            "=" : "equals",
            "!=" : "notEquals",
            "<>" : "notEquals",
            "<" : "lessThan"
            "<=" : "lessThanOrEquals",
            ">" : "greaterThan",
            ">=" : "greaterThanOrEquals",
        };
    }
```

Now the class is testable.

Tanks and regards

Florian